# Subversion server on 64-bit Windows?

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server

I want to set up a Subversion server installation on Windows Server 2003 64-bit and I'm considering using [VisualSVN Server](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/). Does this work OK in a 64-bit environment? Are there any issues or gotchas I should be aware of before installing the software?

Many thanks!

Comment: VisualSVN Server 3.0 provides native 64-bit support.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ive been using VisualSVN Server on W2K3 x64 on one of our MS SQL 2005 boxes with no problems at all for over a month now. I followed the [installation guide](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/doc/server-config/) and have had no issue at all with either the server code or the integrated Apache server.

Comment: Same here - no problems.

Answer (score 4):

VisualSVN 1.5.1 works on Vista 64 bits. You can get some [update here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/applications/CustomVisualSVNServerXSLT.aspx) for Vista if you experiment some problem, but you should be fine.

Answer (score 3):

Okay guys, i got it all working.
So, install VisualSVN. Bbelieve me or not i installed 2.0.8 and after few hours got a message from RSS there is new version - 2.1, so i made an update (at least was able to check the update process, all went just fine).
Then install Ruby (i got 1.8.6), then Gems (1.3.1 is req, but i got 1.3.5)
When you got Ruby and gems, enter cmd and enter: gem install rails -v=2.3.5
then: gem install rack -v=1.0.1

then i got latest Redmine trunk.
Installed MySQL 5.0 (5.1 is not supported), create new DB (via shell or gui tools), redmine user and it's privileges.

Then: gem install mysql
+ copy http://instantrails.rubyforge.org/svn/trunk/InstantRails-win/InstantRails/mysql/bin/libmySQL.dll to ruby/bin

edit config file for redmine and run rack webserver... al should be working.
I had one problem, i was not able to see the repository in newly created redmine project.

Solution - redmine.org/boards/2/topics/show/723

Mine config looks like: SVN_BIN = "svn --trust-server-cert --non-interactive --config-dir c:/Repositories"

So now all is working. My next step, move svn repo from ald pc to that new.
Done :)

Answer (score 1):

I have a lot of experience with SVN servers on windows.

VisualSVN works fine.

However it is x86. If you want your server to run as 64bit process you can do the following(Maybe you can create a hack to work with VisualSVN - Didn't try yet):

> **Update1: This is an obsolete method. There is no need to download this anymore.**
>   Download from here the x64 server process:
>   http://nightlybuilds.tortoisesvn.net/latest/x64/full/svnserve.exe

Now let install the server as a service (That is also what VisualSVN does).

InstallService.bat

```
sc create svnserver binpath= "C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\svnserve.exe --service -r D:\SvnRepositories" displayname= "Subversion" depend= Tcpip start= auto
pause
```

keep the spaces as shown.

If you will ever want to remove it make sure to stop it through services.msc and then run:

UninstallService.bat

```
sc delete svnserver
pause
```

If you are running under Vista/7/2008 You will need to run as administrator.

Hope this helps